# The product of a uniform probability density function and -1

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

What happens when you multiply a uniform probability density function between -1 and 1 by -1? Does the new uniform distribution become -1/2 between -1 and 1?

I am asking because I am trying to find the sum of a negative uniform distribution and a triangular distribution (which gives me a negative gaussian??).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ is uniform on $(-1,1)$ then $-U$ is also uniform on $(-1,1)$

Comment: Ohhhh, duh, thank you!